# How to fix issue NoSuchFolderException with document and media portlet in Liferay 6.1.2-ce-ga3?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

This question is related to Document and Media Portlet in Liferay.

I am using Liferay 6.1.2-ce-ga3 .

I have a portlet that allows to display a list of documents of a directory created in document and media portlet of Liferay.

This portlet project allows to display the list of documents in a table and to download multiple files using Liferay and JavaScript.

When I deploy a new version or update a liferay portlet I get the following issues:

- Issue 1 : NoSuchFolderException

> com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFolderException: No DLFolder
>   exists with the key {groupId=10165, parentFolderId=0, name=}

In Document and Media Portlet the directory already exists. To fix the NoSuchFolder issue I delete the old folder and I create a new one.

- Issue 2 : Ajax error for undefined 404

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Ajax error for undefined : 404
>   Introuvable
>       at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange

This issue is connected to this question : [Why i am getting Ajax error for undefined : 404 Not Found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272672/why-i-am-getting-ajax-error-for-undefined-404-not-found)

To fix the multiple-download issue I delete all the files and I added new one.

I think it's a problem in liferay itself.

I checked the folder and the files, they already exists.

Whenever I deploy a new version or update a portlet liferay, I have the issues. I have to delete the folder and these files each time and create it again.

It does not make sense to recreate the files.

How to fix these issues `NoSuchFolderException` and `Ajax error for undefined 404`?

java code:

```
public class MyPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    private static long ROOT_FOLDER_ID = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    PortletPreferences pref = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    String folders_cfg = pref.getValue("foldersKey", "");
    FOLDERS_NAME = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(folders_cfg.split(",")));
        .
        .
        .
        List<DLFileEntry> listFiles = new ArrayList<DLFileEntry>();
        List<DLFileEntry> listContextFiles = new ArrayList<DLFileEntry>();
        try {
        listFiles = getAllFiles(themeDisplay);
        listContextFiles = getAllFiles(themeDisplay);
        } catch (PortalException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        .
        .
        .
        for(DLFileEntry file : listFiles){
            ...
        }

        List<DLFileEntry> list = getListFiles(listContextFiles, listAllDate);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("listFiles", list);
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    private List<DLFileEntry> getListFiles(List<DLFileEntry> listContextFiles,
        List<Date> listAllDate) {
        List<DLFileEntry> list = new ArrayList<DLFileEntry>();
        for (int i = 0; i <listContextFiles.size(); i++) {
        listContextFiles.get(i).setModifiedDate(listAllDate.get(i));
        list.add(listContextFiles.get(i));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public List<DLFileEntry> getAllFiles(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay) throws PortalException, SystemException{
        List<DLFileEntry> fileEntries = new ArrayList<DLFileEntry>();
        long globalGroupId = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyGroup(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId()).getGroupId();

        for(String folderName : FOLDERS_NAME){
        try {
        Folder folder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(globalGroupId, ROOT_FOLDER_ID, folderName);
        fileEntries.addAll(DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(globalGroupId,folder.getFolderId(),-1, -1, null));

        for(Long subFolder : DLAppServiceUtil.getSubfolderIds(globalGroupId, folder.getFolderId())){
        fileEntries.addAll(DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(globalGroupId, subFolder,-1, -1, null));
        }
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return fileEntries;
    }
}
```

jsp code:

```
<form action="#" id="download_form">
    <liferay-ui:search-container orderByCol="<%=sortByCol%>"
        orderByType="<%=sortByType%>" iteratorURL="<%=actionURL%>"
        delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-documents">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
            <%
                List<DLFileEntry> fileList = (List<DLFileEntry>) request.getAttribute("listFiles");
                OrderByComparator orderByComparator = OrderByComparatorFactoryUtil.create("DLFileEntry", "modifiedDate", false);

                ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                OrderByComparator orderByComparatorDate =        
                        CustomComparatorUtil.getFileOrderByComparator(sortByCol, sortByType);         
                Collections.sort(fileList, orderByComparatorDate);

                results = ListUtil.subList(fileList, searchContainer.getStart(),    
                             searchContainer.getEnd());

               if (fileList.size()< total)
                {
                   total = fileList.size();
                }
               pageContext.setAttribute("results", results);
               pageContext.setAttribute("total", total);
            %>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-results>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="file"
            className="DLFileEntry">
            <%
                ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                String pdfUrl = "", excelUrl = "";
                String logo ="", vendor="", technology="", productType="", flashType="", fileTitle="", fileUrl="", file_name="";

                long globalGroupId = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyGroup(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId()).getGroupId();

                if(file.getExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))
                    pdfUrl = "<a target='_blank' href='"+ themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/documents/" + globalGroupId + StringPool.SLASH + file.getUuid()+"' ><img src='/flash-table-portlet/images/pdf.png' width='20px'/> </a>";
                else if(file.getExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx") || file.getExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("xls") || file.getExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("csv") )
                    excelUrl = "<a target='_blank' href='"+ themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/documents/" + globalGroupId + StringPool.SLASH + file.getUuid()+"' ><img src='/flash-table-portlet/images/excel.png' width='20px'/> </a>";

                String fileDate = dateFormat.format(file.getModifiedDate());
                String logoUrl = "";
                String maxWidth = "120px";
                String marginLeft = "0px";
                String marginTop = "0px";
                try{
                    Map<String, Fields> fieldsMap = file.getFieldsMap(file.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId());
                    Collection<Fields> collectionFields = fieldsMap.values();
                    for (Fields fields : collectionFields) {
                        vendor =  fields.get("vendor").getValue().toString().replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "");
                        if(vendor.equalsIgnoreCase("other"))
                            logo="<strong>Other</strong>";
                        else 
                        {
                             logoUrl = "/flash-table-portlet/images/vendor/"+vendor.toLowerCase()+".gif";
                             logo = "<div class='crop'><img src='"+logoUrl
                                +"' style='margin-left: "+marginLeft
                                +";margin-top: "+marginTop
                                +";max-width: "+maxWidth
                                +";' alt='"+vendor.toLowerCase()+"'/></div>";
                        }
                        technology= fields.get("technology").getValue().toString().replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "");
                        productType =  fields.get("producttype").getValue().toString().replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "");
                        flashType =  fields.get("flashtype").getValue().toString().replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "");

                        if(fields.get("optionaldate") != null ) {
                              DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                              Date optionalDate = inputFormat.parse((String) fields.get("optionaldate").getValue());
                              fileDate = dateFormat.format(optionalDate);
                          }
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                fileUrl = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/documents/" + globalGroupId + StringPool.SLASH + file.getUuid();
                file_name  = file.getTitle() + "." + file.getExtension();
                fileTitle =  "<div style='display:inline'>"+file.getTitle()+"</div>";
            %>

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text cssClass="width-1">
                <input name="<%=file_name%>" type="checkbox" data-url="<%=fileUrl%>"/>
            </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='model'
                cssClass="width-15" value="<%=fileTitle%>" />
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='executive-summary'
                cssClass="width-4" value="<%=pdfUrl%>" />
            <!-- some other search-container-column-text --> ...
        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

        <liferay-ui:search-iterator
            searchContainer="<%= searchContainer %>"
            paginate="${fn:length(listFiles) ge 10}" /> 
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <aui:button cssClass="download-button" id="download_files" type="submit" value="Download"></aui:button>
        </div>
    </liferay-ui:search-container>
</form>
```

**Issue with the Folder:** The NoSuchFolderException issue sometimes appears, I renamed the folder name to reproduce the error.

> com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFolderException: No DLFolder
>   exists with the key {groupId=10256, parentFolderId=0, name=CONTEXT
>   Flash}    at
>   com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.persistence.DLFolderPersistenceImpl.findByG_P_N(DLFolderPersistenceImpl.java:4653)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   ...
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(DLAppServiceUtil.java:924)
>     at
>   com.context.portlet.MyPortlet.getAllFiles(MyPortlet.java:229)
>   at com.context.portlet.MyPortlet.doView(MyPortlet.java:64)

The issue is related with this line: `Folder folder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(globalGroupId, ROOT_FOLDER_ID, folderName);`

**Issue with files:** When I select multiple files and I click download I had this error 404 Introuvable.

> GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 (Introuvable) Uncaught (in
>   promise) Error: Ajax error for undefined : 404 Introuvable at
>   XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange
>   (jszip-utils.min.js?browserId=other&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6102&t=1511981499426:10)
>   GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 (Introuvable) Error: Ajax
>   error for undefined : 404 Introuvable  at
>   XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange
>   (jszip-utils.min.js?browserId=other&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6102&t=1511981499426:10)

In the ***docroot/html*** directory, I have the following files:

1- The ***init.jsp file*** allows to initialize variables, It contains lines like this `String folders_cfg = GetterUtil.getString (portletPreferences.getValue ("foldersKey", "CONTEXT Flash"));`. CONTEXT Flash is the name of the folder.

2- I have a configuration file ***configuration.jsp*** which contains lines like this `<aui:input name="preferences--foldersKey--" label="Folder List" type="text" required="true" value="<%= folders_cfg %>" style="width: 100%;"/>`

3- I have also a ***view.jsp file***, the view part that contains liferay UI Taglib to display the table of documents.

The FOLDERS_NAME variable is initialized in the doView () method of the MyPortlet class:

```
List<String> FOLDERS_NAME = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void doView()...{
    PortletPreferences pref = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    String folders_cfg = pref.getValue("foldersKey", "");
    FOLDERS_NAME = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(folders_cfg.split(",")));
    .
    .
}
```

In the ***docroot/WEB-INF/src*** directory I have 2 files: MyPortlet.java and ConfigurationActionImpl.java.

The ConfigurationActionImpl.java:

```
public class ConfigurationActionImpl extends DefaultConfigurationAction{
    @Override
    public void processAction( PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {  
        super.processAction(portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);

        PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();
    }
}
```

The contents of the variable pref in `PortletPreferences pref = renderRequest.getPreferences();`:

[image: contents of the variable pref]

Comment: By new version, you mean a new version of your application? Could you post a snippet of code that is dealing with the DL?

Comment: @MiroslavLigas Hi, I put the jsp code. I mean by new version, deploying a new .war file after updating the project. I do not know if there is something missing in my code. It is a simple code that allows to display a table that contains documents.

Comment: The JS is complex but seems to e OK. How do you set "listFiles" attribute?

Comment: @MiroslavLigas Hi, I get the "listFiles" attribute from the java code by this line: `renderRequest.setAttribute("listFiles", list);` pls check the java code. I do not think the problem is in the code.

Comment: yes, and I'm interested how you are setting it in the portlet class.

Comment: What is FOLDERS_NAME values? Also can you put entire subset of log and line number where you get this error?

Comment: @Rajesh Hello, I updated the question pls check the code again.

Comment: your problem seems to me as portlet preference is getting reset after you redeploy your portlet. how and which scope your saving preferences? also try to use DLAppLocalServiceUtil instead of Dlappserviceutil

Comment: @Rajesh what do you mean by preference I have an init.jsp file which allows to initialize variables, It contains lines like this `String folders_cfg = GetterUtil.getString (portletPreferences.getValue ("foldersKey", "CONTEXT Flash"));`.  I also have a configuration file configuration.jsp which contains lines like this `<aui:input name="preferences--flashTypeKey--" label="Type liste" type="textarea" value="<%= flashType_cfg %>" style="width: 100%;"/>`

Comment: @Rajesh Is there a problem in the code?

Comment: could you put a logging message on the line that you load the preference? Just to check what is set there all the time. BTW I don't see the code how the FOLDERS_NAME is defined and passed to the getAllFiles method. This value should be passed as a parameter of getAllFiles method.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas The FOLDERS_NAME variable is initialized in the doView() method of the MyPortlet with this line`FOLDERS_NAME = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(folders_cfg.split(",")));` and the folders_cfg variable is initialized in the init.jsp file with this line`String folders_cfg = GetterUtil.getString (portletPreferences.getValue ("foldersKey", "CONTEXT Flash"));` The "CONTEXT Flash" is the name of the folder. This all what I have 3 files in the html directory init.jsp,configuration.jsp and view.jsp and In the src I have 2 files MyPortlet.java and ConfigurationActionImpl.java.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas I updated the question. pls check the code again.

Comment: when you set the value you are using **flashTypeKey** when you are reading the value you using **foldersKey**

Comment: also use the debugger and check the content of the portlet properties.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas Hi, sorry I used this line `<aui:input name="preferences--foldersKey--" label="Folder List" type="text" required="true" value="<%= folders_cfg %>" style="width: 100%;"/>` to set the value of the folder. I updated the code sorry again. What do you mean by "the content of the portlet properties".

Comment: enable the debugger, set the breakpoint after the line where you load the getPreferences() and look at the content of the prefs object.

Comment: @Miroslav The ConfigurationActionImpl class is not used. I can not display the contents of the variable prefs. It is just a class who extends DefaultConfigurationAction.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas Hi, pls how to fix these issues?

Comment: Look at the property in MyPortlet class not the configurationaction

Comment: @MiroslavLigas I put an image of the contents of the variable pref.

Comment: the property is set as you can see so the code should work. When you do new deployments do you only drop the WAR to deploy folder or do you also (removing and) adding the portlet to the page? Portlet preferences are portlet instance specific so they will be deleted always when you remove the portlet.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas I did this from my Eclipse IDE, I drag and drop my project to tomcat server then I click redeploy. sometimes I delete the project from the server and I add It again. These issues sometimes happens locally and even on an online version. What exactly should I do?

Comment: The drag and drop should work fine. Do you get the exception every time you deploy a new war file? If not can you consistently reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MiroslavLigas Hi, sometimes in localhost I have this issue but I got these issues a lot of times when deploying It to an online version. I can not always reproduce the exception. It does not make sense to delete the folder and It files and to create them at each new deployment. Imagine that if I have 100 files or more, what do I have to do?

Comment: No, the root cause needs to be found. You need to find a way how to reproduce consistently. The error message indicates a problem with the folder name. If the portlet preferences are lost for some reason the exception would come. Best thing is to place logging in many places and wait for the probe to surface again so that you have an insight into the app state.